# MSSQL2008-R2 Scheduled Job Infinite Loop

Tags: scheduled-task, sql-server

I have two very similar jobs on a SQL2008r2 instance.  Each one selects data from one of two structurally identical tables and exports it to one of two SQLAzure databases with the same schema every fifteen seconds.  The work is done in SSIS.  For several months, this ran smoothly.

Yesterday at 1:19 AM (i.e. 1:19 on March 24), BOTH jobs apparently began to run and just never stopped. Even though both jobs were running, their respective SSIS packages were NOT.

What could cause this sort of behavior and how can I prevent it from happening again?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the job history (right click on the job, View History) and you should see entries for each of those jobs.  Look at the entry for the time in question and see what ID initiated the jobs at that time.  My guess is someone manually kicked them off.

Comment: It wasn't manual.  It was run by the schedule I defined.

Comment: @Aushin What was the output of the job steps?  Maybe the packages terminated abnormally and the jobs never got a proper return code.

Comment: I'm not sure where I would check that?  And there's only one step.

Comment: @Aushin When you view the job history, expand the job and you'll see the job steps below.  Click on a job step and in the bottom pane you'll see the output of the job step.

Comment: Unfortunately, since this runs every 15 seconds, that job history is lost (only stores 1000 entries).  From memory, I recall that it claimed the job was canceled at Step 1, so that first step had never completed.